# Clarification on Selection sort?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I was doing C and I came across the Selection sort. I'm fairly sure I understand it but just want to make sure. (Please do not mark this question as a duplicate just because there are other questions dealing with selection sort--this is more for understanding than application).

My understanding is (in pseudocode form):

Cycle through array of numbers: Set the first number as lowest. Cycle through the rest, checking each new number to the current lowest. If the new number is lower, then set it to the new lowest. After cycling through, then we know the lowest.

Swap the current lowest element with the first element of the unsorted array. This is now part of the “sorted” section. Cycle through the unsorted section of the array (everything except the first element) and find the new lowest element and assign it to “lowest”. Swap lowest with the first unsorted element. Repeat.

```
for i = 1 to n - 1
  min = i
  for j = i + 1 to n
    if array[j] < array[min]
      min = j
  if min != i
    swap array[min] and array[i]
```

Let me know if I'm off anywhere.

Moreover, if someone could throw together a quick example in actual C of a simple Selection sort, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes correct:

> The selection sort is a combination of searching and sorting. During each pass, the unsorted element with the smallest (or largest) value is moved to its proper position in the array. The number of times the sort passes through the array is one less than the number of items in the array.

---

Simple Selection sort in [c](/questions/tagged/c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int array[100], n, c, d, position, swap;

   printf("Enter number of elements\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

   for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
      scanf("%d", &array[c]);

   for ( c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ) ; c++ )
   {
      position = c;

      for ( d = c + 1 ; d < n ; d++ )
      {
         if ( array[position] > array[d] )
            position = d;
      }
      if ( position != c )
      {
         swap = array[c];
         array[c] = array[position];
         array[position] = swap;
      }
   }

   printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

   for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
      printf("%d\n", array[c]);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
Enter number of elements
4
Enter 4 integers
1
2
6
-7
Sorted list in ascending order:
-7
1
2
6
```

[Source](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-selection-sort)